# Python - not exactly predefined 2D Array overwrites just all elements

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, predefined-variables

Hey I want to create a `2d-Array` with no predefined length and then replace the elements. **without** using `numpy`.

Here a **simplified** version with my Problem:

```
>>> test = 2*[2*[0]]
>>> test[0][0] = "Hello"
>>> print(test)
[['Hello', 0], ['Hello', 0]]
```

This is the output I would like to have:

```
[['Hello', 0], [0, 0]]
```

Comment: @jasonharper Yes thank you seems like i don't know the needed vocab to find such questions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because you are creating a copy of the address of the memory, to create a 2d Array you have to use a list comprehension

```
test = [[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(2)]
```

try use this

Answer (score 1):

Try creating the list with explicit elements

```py
test = list([list([0 for i in range(2)]) for j in range(2)])
```